# Passing text file to argparse argument

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, argparse, spotipy

I am trying to run this script but i get a syntax error. If i add the arguments on the command line one by one it works. But i am trying to pull in the full list of arguments from a .txt file. How can I make this work?

Thank you

```
import logging

import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import spotipy.util as util

logger = logging.getLogger('examples.add_tracks_to_playlist')
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
scope = 'playlist-modify-public,playlist-modify-private'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(scope, client_id='ID',client_secret='SECRET',redirect_uri='REDIRECTURI')

        

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adds track to user playlist')
    parser.add_argument('/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'), action='append', #changed from '-t','--tids'
                        required=True, help='Track ids')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--playlist', required=True,
                        help='Playlist to add track to')
    
    
    

    
    
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = get_args()

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id='ID',
                                                   client_secret='SECRET',
                                                   redirect_uri='REDIRECTURI',
                                                   scope=scope))
    sp.playlist_add_items(args.playlist, args.'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt') 
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Add a `print(args)` to help debug.  And use a reasonable atribute name for that file argument.  FileType only opens the file named by the user.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's test the `argparse` part of your code

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adds track to user playlist')
   ...:     parser.add_argument('/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
   ...:  action='append', #changed from '-t','--tids'
   ...:                         required=True, help='Track ids')
   ...:     parser.add_argument('-p', '--playlist', required=True,
   ...:                         help='Playlist to add track to')
   ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [2] in <module>
    parser.add_argument('/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'), action='append', #changed from '-t','--tids'
  File /usr/lib/python3.8/argparse.py:1362 in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_positional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File /usr/lib/python3.8/argparse.py:1478 in _get_positional_kwargs
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals
```

so the first error - you specified "required" with a `positional` argument.  Such argument is always required.  Lets remove that:

```
In [3]:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adds track to user playlist')
   ...:     parser.add_argument('/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
   ...:  action='append', #changed from '-t','--tids'
   ...:                         help='Track ids')
   ...:     parser.add_argument('-p', '--playlist', required=True,
   ...:                         help='Playlist to add track to')
   ...:
```

Run without any argument strings - two are required:

```
In [4]: args = parser.parse_args([])
usage: ipython3 [-h] -p PLAYLIST /Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: /Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt, -p/--playlist
```

OK, let's specify the two required values - one positional and one flagged:

```
In [6]: args = parser.parse_args(['args.txt', '-p', 'foo'])
```

and look at the resulting `args` namespace:

```
In [7]: print(args)
Namespace(playlist='foo', **{'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt': [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='args.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]})
```

Let's try to access one of those attributes:

```
In [8]: args.'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt'
  Input In [8]
    args.'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt'
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can't use a string like that as an attribute name. Instead you have to use the `getattr` method:

```
In [9]: getattr(args,'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt')
Out[9]: [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='args.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]
```

Note that this is a list with an opened file.  We can "read" it:

```
In [11]: getattr(args, "/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt")[0].read()
Out[11]: 'args.txt\n--foo\n2\n--bar\n2\n'
```

Why is [9] a list - because of the `action='append'.  'append' doesn't make sense with a` positional`, since it can't be repeated.  A` positional` can only be used once.

Now let's close that file:

```
In [13]: getattr(args, "/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt")[0].close()
```

Make a new parser with the flag you used before:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adds track to user playlist')
parser.add_argument('-t','--tids', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                     help='Track ids')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--playlist',
                       help='Playlist to add track to')
```

Now we can easily parse some inputs and look at the `-t` file:

```
In [14]: args = parser.parse_args(['-t','args.txt', '-p', 'foo'])
In [15]: args
Out[15]: Namespace(playlist='foo', tids=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='args.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
In [16]: args.tids
Out[16]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='args.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
In [17]: args.tids.read()
Out[17]: 'args.txt\n--foo\n2\n--bar\n2\n'
In [18]: args.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I follow up until In [8] but after that I am not entirely sure where I need to put the new code?

Comment: What's the purpose of putting that `'/Users/myname/Desktop/newtracks.txt' string in the argument definition?  It doesn't do anything for you, except to make accessing that user input harder.  It doesn't open or read a files with that name (assuming it exists in your directory).  In my case I had a 'args.txt' file in my directory, which I demonstrated reading.